# Как осуществить рандомную выдачу символов в определенном диапазоне

Tags: python

Имеется переменная с английском алфавитом

```
symbols = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Я перебираю и создаю рандомную выдачу 6 символов

```
import random
print(''.join(random.choice(symbols) for i in range(6)))
```

Выводится: `flndhs` из 6 символов

Вопрос, как сделать рандомную выдачу символов в определенном диапазоне, то есть не 6, 
а например с 6 до 10 рандомно?

Псевдокод:

```
print(''.join(random.choice(symbols) for i in randomrange(6-10)))
```

Comment: random.randint(A, B) - случайное целое число N, A ≤ N ≤ B, library = random

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно обойтись без циклов:

```
import random
import string

def rnd_str(min_chars=6, max_chars=10, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    return ''.join(random.choices(alphabet, k=random.randint(min_chars, max_chars)))
```

Тест:

```
In [322]: for _ in range(10):
     ...:     print(rnd_str(6, 10))
     ...:
fcvabkyca
mkrffnzcoi
wqwqgzh
xfbjwldwyi
phgaajl
altxevat
fgzffr
opndpsfr
xixxksh
tbicuajpq
```

PS функция [random.choices()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.choices) была добавлена в Python 3.6

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: стоит обратить внимание, что `random.choices()` сводится к простому циклу в этом случае: `[population[_int(random() * n)] for i in range(k)]` в то время как цикл `[random.choice(population) for _ in range(k)]` может [`getrandbits()` внутри использовать](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b2984ab9a7c458f8b7ed8978c0c95b109116895d/Lib/random.py#L243-L274): отличие может проявиться для `len(population) >= (1 << 53)`